# ReactJS button that returns a google search from name value in table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, jsx, google-search

Im not entirely sure how to word this, but I have a ReactJS app that has a few fields related to recipes. One is the name of the recipe, and I wanted to attach a button to each item that will open a new window that returns a google search of the name value from each item.

cant find anything about this online, dont even know where to start.

Comment: Add the code you have now.

Comment: It's just a link to google with the query string: `https://www.google.com/search?q=search+term` so all you have to do is open a window with that URL

Comment: @Dominik thanks man, that did it,